# Linq to Entities Group By

Tags: sql, linq, group-by

I written the following MS SQL Server query but am having trouble making a linq to entities statement out of it:

Goal is to retrieve leads from the database that are from the past 7 days and then group by day of the week and count the leads per day

```
SELECT      DATEPART(day, DateCreated) AS Day, LEFT(DATENAME(dw, DateCreated), 3) AS DayOfWeek, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM         dbo.[File]
WHERE     (DateCreated > GETDATE() - 7)
GROUP BY DATEPART(day, DateCreated), DATENAME(dw, DateCreated)
ORDER BY Day, DATENAME(dw, DateCreated)
```

Example results are:

Here is a link containing the example results: [link](http://www.hostorlando.com/SQLStatementExample.png)

Any help with an example on how to write this using linq to entities would be very much appreciated. Vb (preferred) or c#?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think LINQ has translations for every built-in SQL function like DATEPART. Could you simply create a view with that logic and add that view to your LINQ2SQL dbml?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var query =
    from f in File
    where f.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
    group f by new { Day = f.DateCreated.Day, DayOfWeek = f.DateCreated.DayOfWeek } into g
    select new
    {
        Day = g.Key.Day,
        DayOfWeek = g.Key.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3),
        Count = g.Count()
    };
```

If you need culture specific name, you can use `Date.ToString("dddd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`:

```
var query =
    from f in File
    where f.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
    group f by new { Day = f.DateCreated.Day, DayOfWeek = f.DateCreated.ToString("dddd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) } into g
    select new
    {
        Day = g.Key.Day,
        DayOfWeek = g.Key.DayOfWeek.Substring(0, 3),
        Count = g.Count()
    };
```

**update:**
Ok, I'm not a VB expert, but for VB you can try something like this

```
    Dim query =
    From f In File
    Where f.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
    Group f By Day = f.DateCreated.Day, DayOfWeek = f.DateCreated.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3)
    Into Group, Count = Count()
```

Comment: I am attempting to use your example. However, my application is written in vb and having a little trouble converting to VB. I used an online c to vb converted to get the following but getting an intellisense error and not sure how to correct. See screenshot [link](www.hostorlando.com/IntellisenseError.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better off not grouping by day and day of week in the Linq-to-SQL but just grouping by date and then extracting the date parts outside of the query (since processing the dates later won't affect query performance):

```
var query = 
    (from f in Files 
        where EntityFunctions.AddDays(f.DateCreated, 7) >= DateTime.Today()
        group f by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(f.DateCreated) into g
        select new { DateCreated = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToList()  // materialize to switch from Linq-to-SQL to Linq-to-Objects
    .Select( g => new { 
                       Day = g.DateCreated.Day,, 
                       DayOfWeek = g.DateCreated.ToString("ddd"),
                       Count = g.Count
                       });
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Let me try and I will post back.

Comment: Hello, any change you can provide your example in vb? I'm having trouble converting it from c to vb. Thanks!